# Problem with ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting [gear curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GearCurve.html), and I observe that for some parameter values `ParametricPlot[]` does not plot all the teeth:

```
gearCurve[a_, b_, n_] := ParametricPlot[
  {
    (a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]]) Cos[t], 
    (a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]]) Sin[t]
  }, 
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Axes -> False];
  gearCurve[10, 5, 38]
```

produces the following image:

[image: problematic gear]

What is going on?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yaroslav Bulatov posted [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572266/618728) addressing this problem on StackOverflow.

Among several good illustrations the answer includes this undocumented option:

```
Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (*radians*) }}
```

Alexey Popkov also gave [an excellent analysis of the Plot algorithm.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7243229/618728)

His answer includes the apparently equivalent but cleaner (in degrees rather than radians as above):

```
Method-> {MaxBend -> (*degrees*) }
```

Example:

```
gearCurve[a_, b_, n_] :=
  ParametricPlot[
    {(a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]]) Cos[t],
     (a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]]) Sin[t]},
    {t, 0, 2 Pi},
    Axes -> False,
    Method-> {MaxBend -> 1}
  ];

gearCurve[10, 5, 38]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note: `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (*value*) }}` was the option known as `MaxBend` in older versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: @J.M. any idea why that option is no longer explicitly supported?

Comment: I don't, sorry. I'd like to know the answer to that question too...

Comment: @J. M., @Mr.Wizard The `MaxBend` option is still supported via `Method -> {MaxBend -> maxBend}` (where `maxBend` is in `Degree`s), see the "Edit 4" part [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7243229/590388) for more information.

Comment: @Alexey it's funny but I thought I remembered Yaroslav's answer being longer; I was remembering contents of your answer as being part of it.  I'll add that to my answer!

Answer (score 16):

Sorry, the engineer inside couldn't resist

[image]

**Edit**

Here is the code:

```
gearCurve[a_, b_, n_, c_, h_] := 
  ParametricPlot[{c + (a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t + h]]) Cos[t + h], 
                      (a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t + h]]) Sin[t + h]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Axes -> False, 
   Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> 1 Degree}}];

Animate[Show[gearCurve[10, 5, 38, 0, h], gearCurve[10, 5, 38, 20, -h],
             PlotRange -> {{-10, 30}, {-10, 10}}], {h, 0, 2 Pi, .01}, 
             DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

Comment: Okay, now [impress me.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkQ2pXkYjRM)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The Wankel thing at 2:03 is really beautiful

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, epicycloids/hypocycloids take a bit more work to do... :)

Comment: I'll give you my +1 after you add the source. (This would make it a much more complete and rounded side-answer:)

Comment: @Ajasja You got it :D

Comment: You don't need to animate the whole 360 when you have 38-fold rotational symmetry.

Comment: @wxffles In my machine there is something like a small jump when one animation finishes and the next is starting. That is the reason.

Answer (score 15):

Just need to bump up `PlotPoints`...

```
gearCurve[a_, b_, n_] := 
  ParametricPlot[{(a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]]) Cos[
  t], (a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]]) Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100];
gearCurve[10, 5, 38]
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to be able to adjust the `PlotPoints` or other options at will: `gearCurve[a_, b_, n_, opts___] := ParametricPlot[{(a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]]) Cos[t], (a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]]) Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, opts, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]`. Better yet, the code is easily compacted: `gearCurve[a_, b_, n_, opts___] := PolarPlot[a + 1/b Tanh[b Sin[n t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, opts, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]`