# Rectangle wave OK in calculations, wrong in Plot

Tags: plotting

I have a Piecewise function consisting of two rectangle waves with different duty cycles:

```
dc1 = 0.7; dc2 = 0.3; period = 1; maxt = 15; 
rectangleWave[t_, period_, duty_] := UnitBox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)]; 
pwm1[t_] := rectangleWave[t, period, dc1]; 
pwm2[t_] := rectangleWave[t, period, dc2]; 
pwm[t_, tsplit_] := Piecewise[{{pwm1[t], t < tsplit}, {pwm2[t], t >= tsplit}}];
Plot[pwm[t, 5], {t, 0, maxt}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

but if I increase my Plot interval beyond 16 I get

[image]

Looks like there's an error in my definition of `rectangleWave`. However, when I use the Piecewise function in a differential equation it is interpreted correctly:

```
dc1 = 0.7; dc2 = 0.3; period = 1; y0 = 0.65; maxt = 18; 
rectangleWave[t_, period_, duty_] := UnitBox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)];
pwm1[t_] := rectangleWave[t, period, dc1]; 
pwm2[t_] := rectangleWave[t, period, dc2]; 
pwm[t_, tsplit_] := Piecewise[{{pwm1[t], t < tsplit}, {pwm2[t], t >= tsplit}}];
c1 = 1; r1 = 2; 
s = NDSolve[{r1 c1 y'[t] + y[t] == pwm[t, 5], y[0] == y0}, y, {t, 0, maxt}];
Plot[{pwm[t, 5], Evaluate[y[t] /. s]}, {t, 0, maxt}, 
        Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Ideas anyone?

Comment: some details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4572266/559318)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8482/121

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks as if it might be that you need to increase the number of points plotted, as in:

```
Plot[pwm[t, 5], {t, 0, maxt}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem crops up again and again.  A better understanding of *Mathematica*'s plot algorithm and options will prevent it from being a surprise.  I highly recommend reading the great answers to these questions:

- [Strange Sin[x] graph in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4572183/618728)
- [How Plot[] works in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7204383/618728)

---

<sub>I realize this answer is in essence a couple of links, and such answers are discouraged.  Nevertheless the alternatives in this case appear *less* desirable.  The decision has been made not to migrate the linked questions.</sub>