# Problem in RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I tried to plot the region bounded by the three planes. This is supposed to give me a pyramid type of shape (actually two, but I am just taking one of them). The code is given by

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x - Sqrt[2]*z >= 0 && Sqrt[2]*x + Sqrt[3]*y + z >= 0 && 
  Sqrt[2]*x - Sqrt[3]*y + z >= 0, {x, 0, 12}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 
  20}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]]]
```

I am getting kinkiness in the lines created by joining of two planes, [image: plot of pyramid]

Is it a problem in my graphics card? However, I have checked in different machines and in versions 6, 7 and 8. I got the same situation in all of them. 
May be it is the similar kind of problem as [posted here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8482/1532). I am not sure exactly what modification has to be made. Advanced thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Increase the number of `Plotpoints`:

```
RegionPlot3D[x - Sqrt[2]*z >= 0 && Sqrt[2]*x + Sqrt[3]*y + z >= 0 && 
  Sqrt[2]*x - Sqrt[3]*y + z >= 0, {x, 0, 12}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 
  20}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image]

Comment: Bah! Beat me to it!

Comment: @rcollyer hehe :)

Comment: But, at least I was showing the evolution of the plot with increasing `PlotPoints`! :)

Comment: Why doesn't increasing `MaxRecursion` help?