# How can I fix a defect in the 3D graphics rendering of a coiled tube?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization

I use the following code to obtain a tube version of a spring:

```
 p = 
   ParametricPlot3D[
     {20 Cos[t]-((837+800 Cos[2 t]-35 Cos[12 t]+40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]) Cos[300 t]+480 Sin[t] Sin[6 t] Sin[300 t])/(-1637+35 Cos[12 t]-40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]),
      20 Sin[t]+(4 (40 Cos[t]+Sqrt[2] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]) (10 Cos[300 t] Sin[t]-3 Sin[6 t] Sin[300 t]))/(1637-35 Cos[12 t]+40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]),
      Cos[6 t]+(480 Cos[300 t] Sin[t] Sin[6 t]+(1565+37 Cos[12 t]+40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]) Sin[300 t])/(-1637+35 Cos[12 t]-40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]])}, 
     {t, 0, 2Pi},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 10]], 
     Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 900, PlotPoints -> 3000] 
       /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1, rest];

Export["testTube01.png",p]
```

which gives:

[image]

However, though I increased the `PlotPoints` option to 3000, there still remained a defect at the upper left corner of the spring:

[image]

How can I obtain a smooth and normal tube version spring without such a defect?

**Update 1**

Per @belisarius suggestion, I tried the following:

```
p=ParametricPlot3D[{20 Cos[t]-((837+800 Cos[2 t]-35 Cos[12 t]+40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]) Cos[300 t]+480 Sin[t] Sin[6 t] Sin[300 t])/(-1637+35 Cos[12 t]-40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]),
20 Sin[t]+(4 (40 Cos[t]+Sqrt[2] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]) (10 Cos[300 t] Sin[t]-3 Sin[6 t] Sin[300 t]))/(1637-35 Cos[12 t]+40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]),
Cos[6 t]+(480 Cos[300 t] Sin[t] Sin[6 t]+(1565+37 Cos[12 t]+40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]]) Sin[300 t])/(-1637+35 Cos[12 t]-40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801+Cos[12 t]])},
{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Orange,Opacity[1],Specularity[White,10]],
Boxed->False,Axes->False,ImageSize->500,
PlotPoints->100,Method->{Refinement->{ControlValue->Pi/360}}]/.Line[pts_,rest___]:>Tube[pts,0.1,rest];
```

and obtained:

[image]

problem persists though looks a little different.

**Update 2**

When I use the following equation per comments by @N.J.Evans, problem is solved:

```
    {20 Cos[t]+((59+100 Cos[t]^2+50 Cos[2 t]+10 Cos[t] Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]-9 Cos[12 t]) Cos[240 t EllipticE[-(9/100)]])/(209+10 Cos[t] Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]-9 Cos[12 t])+(60 Sin[t] Sin[6 t] Sin[240 t EllipticE[-(9/100)]])/(209+10 Cos[t] Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]-9 Cos[12 t]),
20 Sin[t]+(10 (20 Cos[t]+Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]) Cos[240 t EllipticE[-(9/100)]] Sin[t])/(209+10 Cos[t] Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]-9 Cos[12 t])-(3 (20 Cos[t]+Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]) Sin[6 t] Sin[240 t EllipticE[-(9/100)]])/(209+10 Cos[t] Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]-9 Cos[12 t]),
(Cos[6 t] (209+10 Cos[t] Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]-9 Cos[12 t])-10 (6 Cos[240 t EllipticE[-(9/100)]] Sin[t] Sin[6 t]+(20+Cos[t] Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]) Sin[240 t EllipticE[-(9/100)]]))/(209+10 Cos[t] Sqrt[418-18 Cos[12 t]]-9 Cos[12 t])}
```

So it is the wrong equation that causes the defect.

thank you all for suggestions!

Comment: Try using `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> 1 Degree}` as in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8490/193

Comment: `1 Degree` is an example ...

Comment: thanks! from the link you posted, such `Refinement` method works similar to that of increasing the `PlotPoints`, and does not seem to resolve the problem in my test with `ControlValue->Pi/360`

Comment: "does not seem to resolve the problem" - can you then include a picture in your post?

Comment: OK. updated. thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with plot? The expressions for x[t],y[t],z[t] all act funny near pi.

Comment: @LCFactorization , you could always leave it and claim it's a plot of a phone cord from back when phones had cords. That little squiggle always seemed to be in there somewhere.

Comment: Let me check it . thank you!

Comment: I changed the equation and solved the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to study that region where you get the defect try

```
f[t_] := {20 Cos[
     t] - ((837 + 800 Cos[2 t] - 35 Cos[12 t] + 
         40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801 + Cos[12 t]]) Cos[300 t] + 
      480 Sin[t] Sin[6 t] Sin[300 t])/(-1637 + 35 Cos[12 t] - 
      40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801 + Cos[12 t]]), 
  20 Sin[t] + (4 (40 Cos[t] + 
        Sqrt[2] Sqrt[801 + Cos[12 t]]) (10 Cos[300 t] Sin[t] - 
        3 Sin[6 t] Sin[300 t]))/(1637 - 35 Cos[12 t] + 
      40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801 + Cos[12 t]]), 
  Cos[6 t] + (480 Cos[300 t] Sin[t] Sin[
        6 t] + (1565 + 37 Cos[12 t] + 
         40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801 + Cos[12 t]]) Sin[
        300 t])/(-1637 + 35 Cos[12 t] - 
      40 Sqrt[2] Cos[t] Sqrt[801 + Cos[12 t]])}
```

and then wrap it in a Manipulate where you can control the range of the plot

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[f[t],

  {t, tmin, tmax},

  PlotStyle -> Black,
  Boxed -> True,
  Axes -> True,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  PlotPoints -> 100
  ],
 {{tmin, 0}, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 {{tmax, 2 \[Pi]}, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
 ]
```

This results in

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then narrow the range to between 3.1 and 3.2

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can continue on in this manner and increase the PlotPoints and you always see the squiggle.

Are you sure it isn't related to the equation?

Comment: It is because of the wrong equation. thank you1